# Flutter) I want to know how to select and delete canvas shapes

Tags: flutter, canvas

I am developing an online whiteboard app.

I can draw different shapes on the screen using the GestureDetector() and CustomPaint(). And now I'm want to create a function to delete the drew shapes.

The way to delete a shape that I am trying to implement is to delete it from the Shapes List when I tap it, rather than simply overwhite it with a background color.

I think it would be good if I could get a Shape data in the tapped position

Can I get a hint about this?

The following are some of the drawing codes I used

```
// sketcher.dart
class Sketcher extends CustomPainter {
  final List<Shape> shapes;

  Sketcher(this.shapes) : super();

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    for (var shape in shapes) {
      // shape type
      if (shape is Pen) {
        canvas.drawPoints(PointMode.polygon, shape.points, shape.paint);
      } else if (shape is Square) {
        canvas.drawRect(shape.rect!, shape.paint);
      } else if (shape is Line) {
        canvas.drawLine(shape.p1!, shape.p2!, shape.paint);
      }

    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}

// ==================================
// shape.dart

class Shape {} // Origin class for all the shapes

// A curved line consisting of points
class Pen extends Shape {
  final List<Offset> points = [];
  final paint = Paint();

  Pen(Color color, double width) {
    // width 추가
    this.paint
      ..color = color
      ..isAntiAlias = true
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..strokeWidth = width; 
  }
  void add(Offset point) => points.add(point);
}

// Square
class Square extends Shape {
  Rect? rect;
  double? left, top;
  final paint = Paint();

  Square(Color color, double width) {
    this.paint
      ..color = color
      ..isAntiAlias = true
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..strokeWidth = width;
  }
}

class Line extends Shape {
  Offset? p1, p2;
  final paint = Paint();

  Line(Color color, double width) {
    this.paint
      ..color = color
      ..isAntiAlias = true
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..strokeWidth = width;
  }
}

// ==================================
// draw screen code
extension LastElement<T> on List<T> {
  T lastElement() {
    return this[this.length - 1];
  }
}

List<Shape> _shapes = [];

GestureDetector(
  onScaleStart: (details) {
    Tool tool = context.read<DrawProvider>().tool;

    RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    Offset point = box.globalToLocal(details.focalPoint);

    switch (tool) {
      // pen
      case Tool.pen:
        // get seleted tool data
        double seletedPenWidth =
            context.read<DrawProvider>().seletedPenWidth;
        Color seletedPenColor =
            context.read<DrawProvider>().seletedPenColor;

        shapes.add(Pen(seletedPenColor, seletedPenWidth));
        (shapes.lastElement() as Pen).add(point);
        break;

      // shape
      case Tool.square:
        double seletedShapeWidth = 5.0; // TODO
        Color seletedShapeColor =
            context.read<DrawProvider>().seletedShapeColor;

        shapes.add(Square(seletedShapeColor, seletedShapeWidth));

        double left = point.dx;
        double top = point.dy;

        (shapes.lastElement() as Square).left = left;
        (shapes.lastElement() as Square).top = top;
        break;
    }
  },

  onScaleUpdate: (details) {
    Tool tool = context.read<DrawProvider>().tool;

    RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    Offset point = box.globalToLocal(details.focalPoint);

    switch (tool) {
      // pen
      case Tool.pen:

        (shapes.lastElement() as Pen).add(point);
        currentLineStreamController.add(shapes.lastElement() as Pen);
        break;

      // shape
      case Tool.shape:
        double right = point.dx;
        double bottom = point.dy;

        // Rect Shape
        var currentSquare = shapes.lastElement() as Square;

        currentSquare.rect = Rect.fromLTRB(
            currentSquare.left!, currentSquare.top!, right, bottom);

        currentLineStreamController.add(currentSquare);
        break;
    }
  },

  onScaleEnd: (details) {},
  
 child: CustomPaint(
            painter: Sketcher(shapes),
          )
 )
```